# Extracting all dictionaries from a list of lists and dictionaries?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list that contains other lists as well as dictionaries. All lists can contain either lists or dictionaries. Dictionaries, however, cannot contain lists. For example, such a "master list" might look like this:

```
[ [ [ { 'A': 'B' }, { 'C': 'D' } ], { 'E': 'F' } ], { 'G': 'H' } ]
```

How can I extract all the dictionaries from such a list? The results should be:

```
{ 'A': 'B' }

{ 'C': 'D' }

{ 'E': 'F' }

{ 'G': 'H' }
```

Comment: "Dictionaries, however, cannot contain lists". And yet you have this monstrosity: `'E': [ [ [ {'F': 'G', 'H': 'I' }, { 'J': 'K' } ], { 'L': 'M' } ], { 'N': 'O' } ]`.

Comment: Is it an exception because its **The 5th Element**?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem statement contradicts itself. Also, no attempt has been made to think of a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def get_dictionaries(list_obj):
    for item in list_obj:
        if type(item) == list:
            for x in get_dictionaries(item):
                yield x
        elif type(item) == dict:
            yield item
        else:
            raise ValueError("unexpected item type (not a list or a dictionary)")
```

use:

```
top_level_list = [{......
for x in get_dictionaries(top_level_list):
    print x
```

Comment: This does solve the problem, thanks.